# Meta Quest 2 Hand Tracking not working in Unity playmode

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing a VR experience in Unity, using the Oculus Integration SDK. I am using hand tracking to give to the users a more "realistic" way of interaction. At the beginning everything worked fine, but suddenly hand tracking stopped working when testing the experience in play mode with the headset connected through Oculus Link. I tried several fixes, from going back to the last version when it worked to update the HMD, but still it does not work.

The specs of the project are the following:

- Unity v. 2022.3.8f1
- Oculus Integration SDK v. 56.0

The hand tracking option is enabled in the OVRRig.

Anyone have a solution to this problem?